# How to prevent other users from accessing APIs hosted in docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

I have a docker container that hosts REST APIs.
As root user I am able to access with its internal IP from the host machine, like below

```
#docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mycontainer
172.20.0.7

#curl -X GET http://172.20.0.7:8080/v1/api
Welcome!!
```

I can do the same as a non-privileged user too! (Permission denied! If I try to execute docker commands as this user).

**Is there a way, I can prevent non-privileged users from accessing the container APIs?**

Comment: Authenticate the API the way you would any API, for example access tokens.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict access to the container's internal IP for other users?

Comment: No.  You also can't restrict access to the container's published ports, in the same way that any user would be able to connect to a non-container server you were running directly on the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze This is not allowed in MAC OS. I see that the non-privileged users are allowed access to APIs with internal IPs only in linux.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create a network interface which you'll be allow the usage by only your root user by using iptable then cast your service only on this network interface (`-p <your_new_ip>:port:port`)